# Sync between tslint json file and Visual Studio Code

Tags: synchronization, visual-studio-code, tslint

How can I configure the typescript linter of VS Code to be in sync with tslint json file?

Basicaly to intergrate my tslint file into VS Code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

install the TSlint extension in VSCode and put tslint.json file in the home folder

Comment: do you mean to just throw the tslint.json in the home folder of my mac?